# Make fill column indicator visible by default in SpaceVim

Tags: spacevim

I know there is a short cut to make the fill column indicator visible. But I want it visible a most of the time anyway. Can I set an option or call a function to toggle it automatically at startup?

I have used `:nmap [SPC]tf` to show what the key binding does. But I can't understand the result (quite new to vim):

```
n  [SPC]tf     * :<C-U>call call(function('<SNR>32_toggle_colorcolumn'), [])<CR>
```

I have done some more research as suggested by @filbranden. `:scriptname 32` reveals the function:

```
function! s:toggle_colorcolumn() abort
  if !s:ccflag
    let &cc = g:spacevim_max_column
    let s:ccflag = 1
  else
    set cc=
    let s:ccflag = 0
  endif
  call SpaceVim#layers#core#statusline#toggle_mode('fill-column-indicator')
endfunction
```

This seems to toggle a script local boolean s:ccflag (not sure about the script local part) and then calls a function.
Setting the ccflag in my bootstrap function and calling the `toggle_mode()` function did nothing.

Comment: There's this a little above this snippet: `if &cc ==# '80'` and `let s:ccflag = 1`, so maybe `set cc=80` in your early initialization is enough to set it on and keep SpaceVim state consistent? It's odd that that doesn't necessarily match `g:spacevim_max_column`...

Comment: Consider [filing an issue](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/issues) on SpaceVim's GitHub. The author is pretty responsive and should know best how to set this up at initialization. Refer to this question there as well, the author answers questions here so they might be able to post an answer too. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, I investigated that cc setting. Does exactly what I need. It only makes the toggle stumble a bit. If you hit the key binding for the first time after start, it sets cc to g:spacevim_max_column, since the flag isn't set and therefore does not make the columns disappear. I have cc=80 now as well as g:spacevim_max_column.

Comment: I'll update my answer. For now it's only a minor caveat to me that the toggling doesn't work. I'll probably file an issue to have a more easily accessible option. Or maybe there's something we both missed.

Comment: @filbranden Oh, and thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:
I added the following line to my [bootstrap_before function](https://spacevim.org/documentation/#bootstrap-functions)

```
call <SNR>32_toggle_colorcolumn()
```

This comes with the caveat that the function name is likely subject to change.

The above mentioned function sets a variable called cc
Adding the following to the bootstrap function brings up a fill columns indicator (colorcolumn):

```
set cc=80
```

The above setting adds a colored column at column 80. More information under `:help colorcolumn`. This comes with the caveat that the key binding to toggle the color column doesn't work as expected. For best results also set `max_column=80` under options in `~/.SpaceVim.d/init.toml`. Both settings together result in having to hit the toggle shortcut `<Space>tf` twice to make the column disappear, but only the first time after the editor is started.

I filed this as an [issue](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/issues/3987). In case I forget about this question, people can have a look for nicer solutions there.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it relies on the script defining this function being the 32nd one to be loaded... This is quite likely to change as you reconfigure anything, or even with upgrades of SpaceVim itself... There might be better ways to accomplish the same.

Comment: Thought that it looked shady. That's why I didn't mark this as solved yet. Maybe I'll have a look at where this function is defined.

Comment: You can use the `:scriptnames` command and see which script is number 32. (Please [edit] the question and include that information. That might help figure out what that function is doing, and how to enable it by default.)